# Security Deposit Return

Tags: landlord, tenant, deposit, district-of-columbia

My landlord has not returned our deposit and the D.C. legal window to do so has expired. Upon reviewing my lease it says that the tenant must provide an address to return the deposit before the itemized list will be sent. Does this clause supersede the law, or will I be able to file a small claims case to get my deposit back?

Comment: How do you know they don’t have a check with your name on it and just don’t know where to send it?

Comment: I've reached out twice within the legal window to ask about an update.